# logstash runner error

Tags: java, linux, logstash

Does anybody know what is error?

```
  #/usr/java/jre1.7.0/bin/java -cp /home/spatel/logstash logstash.runner agent -f logstash-syslog.conf
    Grok::PatternError: pattern %{IPORHOST:device} not defined
              compile at /home/spatel/logstash/gems/jls-grok-0.10.7/lib/grok-pure.rb:131
                 loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1410
              compile at /home/spatel/logstash/gems/jls-grok-0.10.7/lib/grok-pure.rb:91
              compile at /home/spatel/logstash/gems/jls-grok-0.10.7/lib/grok/pure/pile.rb:51
             register at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/filters/grok.rb:142
                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
             register at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/filters/grok.rb:140
                 each at org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1186
             register at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/filters/grok.rb:126
      run_with_config at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/agent.rb:415
      run_with_config at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/agent.rb:414
                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
      run_with_config at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/agent.rb:412
      run_with_config at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/agent.rb:369
                  run at /home/spatel/logstash/logstash/agent.rb:318
    Exception in thread "LogStash::Runner" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) pattern %{IPORHOST:device} not defined
            at org.jruby.RubyIO.write(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1361)
            at org.jruby.RubyIO.write(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2342)
            at org.jruby.RubyIO.puts(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2297)
            at org.jruby.RubyIO.puts(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2289)
            at logstash.runner.main(logstash/runner.rb:42)
            at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615)
            at logstash.runner.main(logstash/runner.rb:41)
            at logstash.runner.(root)(logstash/runner.rb:120)
```

Comment: The best way to get help with logstash is to use the mailing list or IRC channel since that is where the active community and expert users reside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error when Logstash cannot find that pattern in any of it's pattern files.
The simplest fix would be to use the `patterns_dir` directive in `logstash-syslog.conf` for your filter(s).